# Nodejs twitter api 403

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth, http-status-code-403

I am trying to use the twitter api with nodejs 5.4.1, using [the twitter api as a guide](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search). Initially my bearer access token appears to be generated properly, though when I run the actuall request I keep getting a ['403 Forbidden'](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) error message. Any idea why this is?

```
var R = require("request");
var stream = require('twitter');
var https = require('https');


var key = 'my-key';
var secret = 'my-secret';
var cat = key +":"+secret;
var credentials = new Buffer(cat).toString('base64');

var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token';

R({ url: url,
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + credentials,
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials"

}, function(err, resp, body) {

    var an = JSON.parse(body);
   console.log( an['access_token']);

   runIt(an['access_token']);
    console.dir(body); //the bearer token...

});



function runIt(key){

var options = {
host: 'api.twitter.com',
path: '/1.1/users/search.json?q=Twitter%20API&amp;page=1&amp;count=3',
headers: {
        'Host': 'api.twitter.com',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + key,
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'
}
};

https.get(options,(res)=>{
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        console.log(res);
});

}
```

Comment: What is the message in the 403 response? Check the bottom part of the docs where the common cases are described https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

Answer (score 0):

For Twitter User Api you'll have to follow the proper `oauth` steps to get things work properly.

Initialy there will be 2-step request process that will leave you with `token` and `secret` of user.

You will use that information to sign request with method like HMAC-SHA1 so that you can access data from twitter, [node-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth) can be helpful in this step. [Twitter Link - Authorizing requests](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests)

For further understanding see these tutorials:

- [Implement Twitter Sign](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/how-to-implement-twitter-sign-expressjs-oauth)
- [Nodejs Twitter api](http://webapplog.com/node-js-oauth1-0-and-oauth2-0-twitter-api-v1-1-examples/)

and for code inspiration:

- [Twitter Streamming | A NodeJS Component](https://github.com/zishon89us/twitter-stream-component)